# Finding the solution to $x^2y'' + xy' - 9y = 0$ using the method of Frobenius.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

On plugging in $$y = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nx^{n+s}$$

we have

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[(n+s)(n+s) - 9]a_nx^{n+s} = 0$$

noting that $a_0 \neq 0$, we find the indical equation gives $s = \pm 3$

on plugging in $s = 3$

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}[n(n+6)]a_nx^{n+3} = 0$$

What are the next steps?. I have to get some sort of relationship on $a_n$.
The previous question I have done had $a_n$ and $a_{n-2}$ in it.

Comment: If you don't have to use the method of frobenius, then this is easily solved using Euler-Cauchy method.

Comment: I have to use it sorry :(.

Comment: I think so. Multiplying y' by x^2 and y by x seems to have "sorted " things out a little.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you get $a_n=0$ for $n>0$, thus $$a_0x^3$$ as solution for $s=3$ and $$a_0x^{-3}+a_6x^3$$ for $s=-3$.